# Automatically move messages to a mailbox in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, catalina

This in on macOS 10.15.3, Mail.app version 13.0.

I often receive marketing emails, or order updates from an online purchase, etc. which I move into different mailboxes in Mail.app. Over time, Mail.app learns which mailbox I usually move these kind of messages to. In my MacBook Pro 15" with touch bar, it even shows a 'Move to "SOME MAILBOX"' icon on the touch bar. On other messages which I usually leave in the inbox, it merely shows 'Move to...' without suggesting a mailbox.

Is there a way to make Mail.app automatically move these messages when they're received to the suggested mailbox, without having to manually press this icon in the touch bar?

Note: I know there's a conventional "Rules" tab in Preferences, as well as the Gmail filters feature (all my emails use Gmail). Once upon a time I had enough patience to try to set up these rules for specific senders, etc. Unfortunately, over time, these rules get obsolete as senders change the email they're sending from, and the rules need updating. It's just too much hassle so I've given up on this route. Mail.app does a great job of classifying emails with the feature mentioned above, all I'm looking for is a way to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Gmail account, try going to gmail.com and making the specific senders go to a new folder. This should sync and do it on the Mail app to. I am not aware of any method to make it go to a new inbox.

Comment: I could not follow. Can you elaborate? Aren't you talking about the filters feature, which I explained why I don't want to use?

Comment: That is not what I meant. Sorry, I am now confused my self. You should be able to see that there are two other inboxes other than Primary in Gmail. Senders for marketing will be sent to the Marketing Inbox which you can see in the Mail app too.